# Writing merge sort in C without pointers

Tags: c, function, recursion, mergesort

I am trying to write code for homework in C that will take 10 integers from user input into an array and sort it using a recursive merge sort. We have not gone over pointers yet so I wanted to avoid using that in my code (many online examples use pointers).

Here is my code:

```
/* This code will take input for 10 integers given by the user
into an array, sort them with a recursive merge function
and print the updated array in ascending order. */

#include <stdio.h>
#define ARRSIZE 10

void merge_sort (int arr[], int temp[], int left, int right);
void merge (int arr[], int temp[], int left, int mid, int right);

int main (void){
    int arr[ARRSIZE], temp[ARRSIZE], left, right, i;

    printf("Enter 10 integers for an array:");
    for(i=0;i<ARRSIZE;i++){
        printf("\narray value %d:", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }
    left = 0;
    right = ARRSIZE-1;

    merge_sort(arr, temp, left, right);

    printf("\nHere is your updated array:");
    printf("\n{");
    for(i=0;i<ARRSIZE;i++){
        printf("%d,", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("}");

    return 0;
}

void merge_sort (int arr[], int temp[], int left, int right){
    if(left<right){
        int mid = (right-left)/2;
        merge_sort(arr, temp, left, mid);
        merge_sort(arr, temp, mid+1, right);
        merge(arr, temp, left, mid, right);
    }
}

void merge (int arr[], int temp[], int left, int mid, int right){
    int i, j, tempi = 0;
    for(i=left, j=mid+1; i<=mid && j<=right ;){
        // mid+1 is the start of the right array
        if(arr[i]<arr[j] && i<=mid){
            temp[tempi] = arr[i];
            tempi++;
            i++;
        }
        else if(arr[i]>arr[j] && j<=right){
                temp[tempi] = arr[j];
                tempi++;
                j++;
             }
    }
    for(i=0,j=right; i<=j; i++){
        arr[i] = temp[i];
    }
}
```

I keep getting a segmentation fault when I run this in my linux shell. Any suggestions?

Comment: on which line is seg fault?

Comment: My shell doesn't tell me, I type in a.out and it just runs. I know that the fault is somewhere in my merge or merge_sort function though.

Comment: even in the debug build?

Comment: compile using gcc -o merge-sort -g merge-sort.c, then run it under gdb: gdb ./merge-sort

Comment: btw, technically speaking, when you pass an array to a function it becomes a pointer..

Comment: You say you're not using pointers but your `merge` and `merge_sort` functions each takes two pointers as arguments.

Comment: I don't know how to debug, at least in my shell. I have visual studio, but things like "Unhandled exception at 0x775bb812 in merge sort.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00230fdc." are what pop up when I try to run my build.

It all compiles correctly, but I can't locate this problem. I was told that the segmentation fault probably lies in one of my array indexes.

Comment: @iain what exactly are you doing with the -o and -g there? When I compile I usually just use gcc -std=c89 filename.

and what is that gdb bit there doing? Because I'm in my shell and it before each line now it says (gdb), but I don't know what to do now.

Comment: @Zelmec -o sets the output filename, so instead of a.out,it will be called merge-sort, and -g means include debugging information so that you can run it in a debugger (like gdb) and get something useful

Comment: @iain Thank you very much! I feel like I should of know that :P

I have a lot left to learn obviously

Comment: @Zelmec everyone has to start somewhere.Learning how to do even a few minor things in a debugger will certainly help you when you're learning C. Here's a beginners tutorial for gdb: http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~sugih/pointers/summary.html

Comment: Just for starters, try `man gdb`. The [GDB documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/) will also help.

Comment: @iain does my file have to be in the form of an executable to be debugged?

Comment: @Zelmec yes,because the debugger runs the executable binary rather than looking at the source code

Comment: @iain okay, thank you very much! I suppose I will just have to use Visual studio to get an executable. Do I need to include anything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I've found one subtle bug already: `int mid = (right-left)/2;` should be `int mid = (left+right)/2;`

Also, what flows I've found:

1. You should use `tempi = left` for simplicity. Simply copy incoming part of array to corresponding part of temporary array.
2. In your merge cycle, you can place incrementing tempi inside `for` definition:

   for( ...; ...; ++tempi)
3. Inside that loop you check boundaries *AFTER* you have read values from that place. This is very bad. VERY. Although, You haven't encounter any problems here just because you are checking boundaries inside `for` definition :) simply remove them:

   ```
   for (i = left, j = 1 + mid; i <= mid && j <= right; ++tempi)
   {  
       if (arr[i] < arr[j])        temp[tempi] = arr[i++];
       else /* arr[j] <= arr[i] */ temp[tempi] = arr[j++];
   }
   ```
4. Cause this loop exits when either subarray has reached end, you have to copy rest of items from another subarray to temp[]:

   ```
   if (i > mid) i = j; /* if we need to copy right subarray */
   for (; tempi <= right; ++tempi, ++i) temp[tempi] = arr[i];
   ```
5. So, your copying back from temporary array will look like

   ```
    for (i = left; i <= right; ++i) arr[i] = temp[i];
   ```

Comment: I'm still getting a fault though. I'm trying to figure out if I have a line that causes me to index beyond the bounds of my array

Comment: Well, I've found another way to improve merge: when main for-loop is done, we can have 2 situations: 1. We've ended left sub-array. 2. We've ended sub-array. In first situation we don't need to copy elements to the right of `j` to `temp` and then back to `arr`. Simply `if (i > mid) right = tempi;` and we are done. This change to `right` variable is local, and can optimise a lot of our work :)

Comment: Wait, so does 'if (i > mid) right = tempi;' take the place of the line 'if (i > mid) i = j;'? and would this affect the 'for(; tempi <= right; ++tempi, ++i)' loop?

Comment: yup. It will affect that line and the last line (copying back from temp to arr). If you can't get it just now, try understand first solution.

Comment: yeah, I am starting to understand your first solution. All the first changes just shortens and streamlines my code. Then you use the next for loop to add the remaining arr values to temp.

So setting tempi = right just skips the second for loop?

Comment: Yup, it skips loop `for (; tempi <= right; ++tempi, ++i) temp[tempi] = arr[i];` and shortens last loop (if it can). Simply, we do not need to copy rest of items from right sub-array. They are already on their places

Comment: or setting right = tempi rather. And then you don't need to edit those values in the array because you are assuming they are in the right order, I see.

However, even with all of these changes, I still receive a segmentation fault.....

Comment: Have you changed initial value of `tempi` to `left` ?

Comment: Yeah, I put it in the declaration where it used to have int... tempi = 0. I can't imagine what is causing this fault

Comment: Can you show your test data? (your test array that cause segfault)

Comment: Enter 10 integers for an array:
{3, 5, 7, 6, 8, 9, 10, 2, 1, 4} which was followed by
"Segmentation fault". 

This is the output I got

Comment: Well, it seems I've said something wrong above, but I can find anything -_-. [Here](http://pastebin.com/CjCScChF) is merge sort that does work for me.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate all of the help either man! You've been invaluable!

Comment: Also, after comparing my code with the one you provided I found out that I just forgot to change my mid definition.